# AngularJS not loading on Plunker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plunker

I launched Plunker and used their add button to add `Angular` to my project.

But it is not working. When I use the view tab, it is just showing the angular expression like a normal text.

https://plnkr.co/edit/wDOkQK9seCbpZnPfebj3?p=preview

Here is what Plunker looked like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-snapshot/angular2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    {{ 20 / 4 }}
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have chosen Angular 2.0 without including `System.js`. The console even shows *"angular2.js:3010 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined"*. Looks like you want Angular 1.x instead ~ https://plnkr.co/edit/O6VLLaUIK6gDEWOtVWrs?p=preview

Comment: @Phil I am following PluralSight Getting Started With Angular JS by Scott Allen, watching his screen and following it.  He did not add System.js

Comment: I bet he didn't add Angular 2.0 either

Comment: @Phil Ok thanks, don't be angry at me!  It is my first five minutes of life I had started learning Angular !!

Comment: Not angry, just forgot the winky-face ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the angular version 2.0 you should replace with 1.x

```
  <script   src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/4HRazUm4HcARyvS8nksD?p=preview)

Comment: This question really didn't need an answer beyond a simple comment and a close vote

Comment: Ok will remove the answer

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: @Phil (y)..... but comment does not help to increase reputation point :P.